# Odd result, error creating Azure KeyVault Policy based on existing BuiltIn Policy - provider referenced by the 'field' property doesn't exist

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-policy

So... I'm having some difficulty converting one of the builtins into a custom. (Why am I doing that? Internal matter, whether I agree or not is irrelevant, so please don't dis me on that decision. :-) )

**Existing BuiltIn Policy:**

https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Key%20Vault/Certificates_ValidityPeriod.json

The problem is coming in lines 40/43 of the json file.

**main.tf file consists of:**

```
# policy
locals {
  json_keyvault_certmaxvalidityperiod = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resourceprovider/KeyVault/Certificates should have the specified maximum validity period.json"))
}

resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "CertificatesShouldHaveSpecifiedMaximumValidityPeriod" {
  name         = "CertificatesShouldHaveSpecifiedMaximumValidityPeriod" # must match output.tf and ad ID to main
  policy_type  = "Custom"  #Must always be Custom
  mode         = "All"
  display_name = "CertificatesShouldHaveSpecifiedMaximumValidityPeriod" #add Custom to display name
  description  = "Manage your organizational compliance requirements by specifying the maximum amount of time that a certificate can be valid within your key vault."
  metadata     = jsonencode(local.json_keyvault_certmaxvalidityperiod.properties.metadata)
  policy_rule  = jsonencode(local.json_keyvault_certmaxvalidityperiod.properties.policyRule)
  parameters   = <<PARAMETERS
    {
        "effect" : {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy",
                "displayName": "Effect"
            }
        },
        "maximumValidityInMonths": {
            "type": "integer",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The limit to how long a certificate may be valid for. Certificates with lengthy validity periods aren\u0027t best practice.",
                "displayName": "The maximum validity in months"
            }
        }
    }
  PARAMETERS
}
```

Using the json content as-is, performing `terraform apply` returns:

```
│ Error: creating/updating Policy Definition "CertificatesShouldHaveSpecifiedMaximumValidityPeriod": policy.DefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidProviderNameInPolicyAlias" Message="The policy definition 'CertificatesShouldHaveSpecifiedMaximumValidityPeriod' rule is invalid. The provider 'Microsoft.KeyVault.Data' referenced by the 'field' property 'Microsoft.KeyVault.Data/vaults/certificates/properties.validityInMonths' of the policy rule doesn't exist."
```

So, I looked at the definitions of the Microsoft.KeyVault.Data provider, and from the following, it looks like there shouldn't be "certificates", instead, it should be "secrets":

https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Key%20Vault/Certificates_ValidityPeriod.json

BUT... if I update lines 40/43 to reflect Microsoft.KeyVault.Data/vaults/secrets, the `terraform apply` returns:

```
│ Error: creating/updating Policy Definition "CertificatesShouldHaveSpecifiedMaximumValidityPeriod": policy.DefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidProviderNameInPolicyAlias" Message="The policy definition 'CertificatesShouldHaveSpecifiedMaximumValidityPeriod' rule is invalid. The provider 'Microsoft.KeyVault.Data' referenced by the 'field' property 'Microsoft.KeyVault.Data/vaults/secrets/properties.validityInMonths' of the policy rule doesn't exist."
```

Has anyone dealt with anything like this previously? Suggestions as to how to define the policy rule so as to fit the data provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to create keyvault policies with custom policy type as `"Microsoft.Keyvault.Data"` is supported only for built-in policy types as stated in **Microsoft Document** given in reference.

If you see in [`Azure Policy Extension in Visual Studio Code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/extension-for-vscode) you can find all the properties of the resource providers present in azure but for keyvault its not present , they are empty.

**Reference:**

[Details of the policy definition structure - Azure Policy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#resource-provider-modes)